# Get a file from a different directory

Tags: ruby

Alright, I'm trying to open a file 'gamewindow.rb' from a MyScripts folder I've tried

```
Dir.open "Users/NAME" do |dir|
require 'gamewindow.rb'
end
```

This shows up with the error:

```
body.rb:1:in no such file or dir
```

I've also tried just;

```
require 'gamewindow.rb'
```

this shows up with the error:

```
C:/ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
cannot load such file -- gamewindow.rb
```

I've also tried:

```
Dir.pwd #"Users/NAME/MyScripts"
require 'gamewindow.rb'
```

this shows up with the same error as above, and I've tried countless other things, am I using the wrong directory change? Can I change which directory Ruby searches through?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require` will search for files in only a set of locations referred to as the `Load Path.` You can view the load path by using the global variable `$LOAD_PATH` in a script or irb session.

So, you can just do this (assuming the `gamewindow.rb` file is present in `C:/Users/NAME/MyScripts` directory):

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.join('C:', 'Users', 'NAME', 'MyScripts')
require 'gamewindow'
```

Comment: got this again:
     ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
     cannot load such file -- gamewindow.rb

Comment: what do you see when you do: `pwd` inside the folder where the `gamewindow.rb` file is?

Comment: C:/ruby22/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
cannot load such file -- gamewindow.rb

Comment: not this, in your shell, if you go to the `MyScripts` directory and type: `pwd` whats the output? this should give you the full path of your current directory

Comment: C:/Users/NAME/MyScripts

Comment: can you try this? `$LOAD_PATH << File.join('C:', 'Users', 'NAME', 'MyScripts')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90707/discussion-between-k-m-rakibul-islam-and-ekultek).

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path.

```
Dir.open "Users/NAME/you_script_folder" do |dir|
  require "#{dir.path}/gamewindow.rb"
end
```